# Limiting spaces in looped stringbuilder

Tags: java, for-loop, stringbuilder

I'm stumped and have no idea how to do this. I'm creating a method that will take a String[] as an argument and build it into a string. Then my main method will use the output from this method as name for a fileWriter. The rest of the code is in place.

```
public static String nameFromString (String[] args){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
        builder.append(args[i]);
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    return builder.toString();  
}
```

If I, for example, write "**new My File**" in my program, it uses "**My file**" as a name and the main method appends a "**.txt**". So far, no problems.

But my problem, right now, is that it names the file "**My File .txt**" and also, when reading a file, using this same method, it tries to read "File name .txt" instead of "**File name.txt**".

How do I remove this last space in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to make the call to `append` conditional on the loop index:

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    builder.append(args[i]);
    if (i < args.length - 1) {
      builder.append(" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [String.trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29) method to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
String str = " ab c  ".trim(); // -> "ab c"
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a lot of answers with index or buffer checking here. I just want to share a piece of code I use often and it is based on Guava `Joiner` class:

```
String result = Joiner.on(' ').join(args);
```

It is really small and clever solution from Google. Also it is optimized and uses `StringBuilder` inside..

Answer (score 0):

You could use an "insert", or you could modify your append or you could `trim()` as follows

**APPEND** very similar to your initial just add the if.

```
if (i + 1 < args.length) { // added if.
  builder.append(" ");
}
```

**"INSERT"** change the loop a little

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
  if (i != 1) {
    builder.append(" ");
  }
  builder.append(args[i]);
}
```

**TRIM** change the return like this

```
return builder.toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this can be achieved. I use to delete the last character from the `StringBuilder` after the loop had completed, but this requires you to ensure that the last character is a space, instead, I know use...

```
for (int i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (builder.length() > 0) {
        builder.append(" ");
    }
    builder.append(args[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to append one string ahead and then continue just toggling the append sequence:

```
if(args.length < 2)return "";

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(args[1]);

for (int i = 2; i < args.length; i++) {
        builder.append(" ");
        builder.append(args[i]);

    }

return builder.toString();
```